How to disable built-in camera in macOS Sonoma?
I have an app which does not allow to choose another camera when my laptop is connected to a monitor with a camera on top.
I'd like block built-in camera to forward this app to use another camera. I tried a couple of solutions but seem they are obsolete.
Do we have some tricks or tools to manage camera availability on macOS Sonoma 14.6.1?

Your best bet is contacting the developer of the app to allow camera selection.

@benwiggy, it might be better, but it's a long game.

So this article: How to Completely Disable the FaceTime Camera on a Mac could be an option, but it requires to disable SIP (System Integrity Protection) which you might not want to do, if you don't really know what you are doing.
These are the steps to disable the FaceTime camera as described in the article:

Turn Off SIP (System Integrity Protection)
This is necessary for the process to work. Follow the official documentation or the guide posted here on how to disable it.

Issue the Following Terminal Commands
Once you are done disabling SIP on your Mac, launch a new Terminal window from Applications/Utilities folder in Finder, or the Launchpad. Now type in the following five commands in the order they are written:


sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/VDC.plugin/Contents/MacOS/VDC
sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaIOServicesPrivate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AVC.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AVC
sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer
sudo chmod a-r /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera
sudo chmod a-r /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/FCP-DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera

Once you are done, launch any app that utilizes the FaceTime camera, such as Photo Booth. You will notice that the camera fails to initiate at all, confirming that the issued commands were successful.

Last but not the least, make sure you turn SIP back on.

PS: To re-enable the FaceTime camera again, to the above but use sudo chmod a+r ....

The link is from 2017. Does this work on recent OSes, where the system files are read-only, and signed to prevent tampering?

I haven't tried but you can modify locked files for sure.
